# Measure convergence of $\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

[image]

**(1)**If $lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$, then why have $lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\{ x\in D:|f_n-f>0|\}=1$? Is this a proof by contradiction?

**(2)**Does(1) imply the condition (a) is true or false?

Comment: "By Lebesgue Theorem"?!  What is this theorem being invoked to prove that $\frac1n\to 0$ in measure?

Comment: I think it's because the measure of $[a,b]$ is $b-a$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Probably the  theorem that says that pointwise converge implies convergence in measure

Comment: @Ant: Probably but that's really weird.  It converges uniformly, there's no $x$ in it, nothing that brings to mind using a theorem if one knows what the definition is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $\{x \in D: |f_n(x) - f(x)| > 0\}$ is *equal* to the set $[0,1]$. So you have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu([0,1]) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 = 1$$

1) is just saying that the converse of a) is not true. So a) is true, but its converse is false, as they show in 1)

**EDIT**

So, what they are saying is the following: We know that convergence in measure is defined as

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0: \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu\{x \in D: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \ge \varepsilon\} = 0$$

The more $\varepsilon $ is small, the harder it is to make the measure of that set "small". What happens then when $\varepsilon = 0$? In that case, the condition becomes

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu\{x \in D: |f_n(x) - f(x)| > 0\} = 0$$

Intuitively, it seems that this condition is stronger than the previous one. It is true, and this is what they are saying. They are saying that

1. The fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu\{x \in D: |f_n(x) - f(x)| > 0\} = 0$ implies convergence in measure, i.e. implies that $\forall \varepsilon > 0: \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu\{x \in D: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \ge \varepsilon\} = 0$. So the second condition implies the first.
2. The fact that $\forall \varepsilon > 0: \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu\{x \in D: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \ge \varepsilon\} = 0$ **does not** imply $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu\{x \in D: |f_n(x) - f(x)| > 0\} = 0$.

So the condition is strictly stronger than what is requires for convergece in measure. How do they show this? With the following argument:

$f_n = 1/n$ is a sequence that converges almost uniformly to $f = 0$. Therefore, it must also converge in measure, therefore it must be that $\forall \varepsilon > 0: \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu\{x \in D: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \ge \varepsilon\} = 0$. On the other hand, we can see how $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu\{x \in D: |f_n(x) - f(x)| > 0\} = 1 \neq 0$. Therefore, it must be that convergence in measure does not imply the other condition, which is precisely what point 2) above is saying.

Comment: I had already figured this out$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu([0,1]) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 = 1$. The problem is that I do not understand what you mean "1) is just saying that the converse of a) is not true. So a) is true, but its converse is false, as they show in 1)". What is 1) for you? Secondly are you saying $lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\{ x\in D:|f_n-f>0|\}=0$ is true and $lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\{ x\in D:|f_n-f>0|\}=1$ is false?

Comment: @PedroGomes Do you know what the converse of a) is? Because I think that's where your confusion stems from. Can you write down the converse of a?

Comment: I guess the converse of a) is $lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\{ x\in D:|f_n-f>0|\}>0$

Comment: @PedroGomes No. It is that **if** $f_n \mathop{\to}^\mu f$, *then* $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu\{x \in D: |f_n - f|\} = 0$. It is the "inverse implication" of the theorem stated in point a). So they show that this does not hold by showing a sequence that converges in measure but for which that limit is $1 \neq 0$.

Comment: I guess I begin to understand. Are you saying that $\frac{1}{n}$ does not converge in measure on $[0,1]$? How can this be? Am I missing something on that function properties?

Comment: @PedroGomes Exactly; $1/n$ does *not* converge in measure on $[0,1]$. Look at the proof! The measure of the points where the function is differnet than $0$ is equal to $1$ for every $n$, so the limit of the measure is $1 \neq 0$

Comment: The expression $\mu\{ x\in D:|f_n-f>0|\}=1$ means $\frac{1}{n}$ does not converge in measure. Right? How can this be?

Comment: @PedroGomes Look here, it may clarify a lot of things about the relations between the different notions of convergence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_4

Comment: I have looked at article on Wikipedia. However, I would like if possible an answer to my question. My question is  rethoric question. I know that given $\mu\{ x\in D:|f_n-f>0|\}=1$ does not imply that function $\frac{1}{n}$ converges. Is it right? I believe the function converges to 0, so that $lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\{ x\in D:|f_n-f>0|\}=0$. What is going wrong with my line of thought?

Comment: @PedroGomes The thing is that there are **several** notions of convergence. Saying just "converges" does not mean anything. Converges how? Uniformly? Pointwise? Almost surely? In mean? In measure? In distribution? Once you estabilished which kind of convergence you are talking about, you can ask: If it converges pointwise, does int converge in mean? If it converges in measure, does it converge in distribution? Is the converse true? The statement you are talking about says precisely this: converges in measure implies convergence in distribution

Comment: @PedroGomes but the converse is NOT true, that is: convergence in distribution **does not** imply convergence in measure. The article I linked on wikipedia contains the definition of several notion of convergence (see how convergence in probability is defined precisely by saying that the limit of the meausure of that event goes to 0!) and also contains a helpful chart that shows what kind of relationships there are between the different types of convergence

Comment: Lemma: $f_n\to f$ almost uniformly$\rightarrow f_n\to f $ in measure. I thought this was tacit, when I referred to convergence.

Comment: "we say that $f_n$ converges in measure ($\mu$) to $f$ if, for each $\epsilon>0$,  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geqslant\epsilon\}=0$"

Comment: Therefore the function cannot converge **in measure**. Right?

Comment: @PedroGomes Ah, sorry, I had a slight misunderstanding about the nature of your question. I have updated my answer; please take a look and see if it is more clear :)

Comment: Yes I am understanding it now. Because given $\epsilon>0, n\geqslant N, |\frac{1}{n}-0|<\epsilon$ but it is still higher than zero($\epsilon>0$), right? Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @PedroGomes Yes exactly. You're welcome! :)